# To store session and retrieve using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In the below codeigniter code i placed model and view.My aim is to store college name in session and retrieved and used in other tables.Pls help me to do this.
Model:

```
function validate()
    {
        $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
        $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
            $this->db->where('college_name', $this->input->post('college_name'));
        $query = $this->db->get('membership');

        return $query;

    }
```

view:

```
<?php 
    echo form_open('login/validate_credentials');
    echo form_input('username', 'Username');
    echo form_password('password', 'Password');
        echo form_input('college_name', 'college_name');
    echo form_submit('submit', 'Login');
    echo anchor('login/signup', 'Create Account');
    echo form_close();
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To initialize the Session class manually in your controller constructor, use the `$this->load->library function:`

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

To add your data to the session array involves passing an array containing your new data to this function:

```
$this->session->set_userdata($array);
```

You can set array in session like :

```
$newdata = array(
                   'username'  => 'johndoe',
                   'email'     => 'johndoe@some-site.com',
                   'logged_in' => TRUE
               );

$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

For further details please study this [link](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html).

Answer (score 0):

To set data in session :

```
$this->load->library('session');
$this->session->set_userdata("collegeName",$collegeName);
```

To get data use :

```
$data = $this->session->userdata("collegeName");
```

For more info : (http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Comment: how to use this collegename in other tables

Comment: $data will give you that value.You can use $data as collegeName